# Защита взаимодействия с сервером приложения в социальной сети

Tags: защита, архитектура

Доброго времени суток!
Поделитесь пожалуйста информацией, как реализовать защищенное взаимодействие клиента приложения в социальной сети с сервером?
Предполагается такое взаимодействие: приложение обращается к серверному методу login и передает id пользователя в социальной сети, в ответ получает токен. С этим токеном клиент дальше обращается к серверу. А что будет, если злоумышленник обратится к методу login с id жертвы? Токен честного пользователя затрется, а это совсем нехорошо.

Клиент на Flash
Сервер Python/Django
Взаимодействие polling

Comment: Поидее надо передавать связку логин/пароль и только в случае корректности обоих выдавать токен. При авторизации всегда использовать шифрованный поток. Или не совсем понял вопрос?

Comment: Описанное вами действие нельзя назвать авторизацией. Метод "login" должен принимать данные, известные только пользователю. Иначе злоумышленник сможет получить токен для любого юзера, и это, как вы сами написали, не есть хорошо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ВКонтакте после успешной авторизации выдает токен + подпись строки ответа, которая вычисляется с использованием закрытого ключа приложения, известного только девелоперу.
Таким образом любой запрос в приложение сопровождается этой подписью, которую приложение может проверить.

Дальнейшие запросы к методам приложения, напр. через ajax, я также сопровождаю этой подписью, и в каждом запросе перепроверяю.
Угроза тут только в перехвате трафика, который идет по открытому каналу без шифрования. Т.е. злодей теоретически может перехватить связь жертвы с ВК и овладеть token'ом в купе с подписью. Но у нас же не банковская система )

Comment: Да, действительно. Флешовое приложение получает токен социальной сети, и с ним можно сделать запрос как с фронтэнда, так и с бэкэнда. Достаточно будет проверить этот токен на валидность на стороне бэкэнда и можно считать, что все хорошо :)

Всем спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 2):

Сеть социальная, значит пользователь уже выполнил вход.

Значит у него уже есть какие-то токены из социальной сети.

При запуске приложения передавать этот токен - и по нему уже обращаться к API соц.сети.

У фейсбука, например, токен передается вроде как через `oauth_token`. Этот токен используется для доступа к АПИ пользователя. Если токен недействительный, то АПИ вернет ошибку, а значит и клиенту посылать ошибку.

Остается проблема с тем, что токен пользователя могут украсть.

Но у него (у токена), во-первых, есть время жизни. А значит им смогут воспользоваться только некоторое время.

А во-вторых, если токен украли, то могут вроде как по нему выполнить вход в соц.сеть. А значит и воспользоваться вашим приложением. И вы при этом не будете знать - это "свой" или "чужой", так что не заморачивайтесь

Т.е. по сути - во время логина вы через этот токен можете получить UID пользователя в соц. сети, по UID'у выдать клиенту уже свой токен и работать через него.

И вам писали в комментариях - "Метод "login" должен принимать данные, известные только пользователю" - токен пользователя в соцсети и есть по сути "данные, известные только пользователю"

Answer (score 2):

facebook действительно использует oauth. Как происходит взаимодействие можете почитать здесь:

`http://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/permissions-login-dialog/`

А вообще, можете зарегистрироватся на фейсбуке как девелопер и создать тестовое приложение. Документация прямо на сайте. Информация будет для вас полезной даже если вы планировали работать с другой социальной сетью